# Ubuntu software center error due to package dependencies during download

Tags: package-management, wine, software-center

That's a bit of an exaggeration because I have downloaded an e book reader and stellarium but when it came to downloading rather important things like a video player or wine compatibility layer ( and way more ), it gave me this box:   [error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSvGJ.png)
 and this one as well [error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Stfap.png) and I clicked report each time and nothing has happened yet. I'm new to Linux and I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: I can't see the images you posted bc I'm at work right now, however if you're really stuck and need to install something now then open a terminal (search for terminal in the dash) and use the apt command.Search for a package: `sudo apt search <packagename>`. Install a package: `sudo apt install <packagename>`. Answer Y to install the recommended packages (if that's what you want). When searching you don't have to be exact to find a package, although sometimes this will show you more than you want.

Comment: well i don't even know the names of the packages i need......http://packages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search_packages.pl?keywords=mplayer& .... ive stumbled upon this but i dont know how to use it

Comment: Ok so you want to install a video player "mplayer". `sudo apt install mplayer` <press Enter>. Answer "y" or hit enter when prompted. For good measure you probably want a graphical controller for the player so you could also install mplayer-gui `sudo apt install mplayer-gui`

Comment: okay one last question , i typed that in the terminal and it asks for my password, now when i type it it doesnt show it and tha happened thrice. what do i do and should i remove password for now or what ?

Comment: You won't see your password, or any other characters when typing your password in a terminal. This is a security feature. Just type your password and press the Enter key. If you got your password wrong it will ask again (max 3 times I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple. You are not using Ubuntu 16.04 which has gnome application manager. The default application manager in ubuntu is slow and buggy. Upgrade to ubuntu 16.04.

If you didn't like this solution then try using `aptitude`. You first have to install it using `sudo apt-get install aptitude` and then install the packages using `sudo aptitude install wine`. It will automatically try to solve the problem. Read more about it by typing `man aptitude` in the terminal after installing it.

If nothing works, then try typing `sudo apt-get -f install <PACKAGE NAME>`. Then tell what exactly happens in each case.

Comment: okay so how do i update ? also would any info be lost if i do so ?

Comment: kay one last question , i typed that in the terminal and it asks for my password, now when i type it it doesnt show it and tha happened thrice. what do i do and should i remove password for now or what ?

Comment: i unlocked my account and yet it still asks for password in the terminal

Comment: the terminal doesn't display the length of the password. Just type it and enter it.

Comment: i did and then here's what it said cuz i cant paste pic

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/iijj2hppdmel5ik/Screenshot%20from%202016-10-11%2022%3A58%3A27.png?dl=0 so here's what it shows when i did

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8u3t3sxsprg0s9x/Screenshot%20from%202016-10-11%2023%3A01%3A22.png?dl=0 and the one u suggested

Comment: You are not supposed to add spaces in apt-get. It is supposed to be written as 'sudo apt-get install aptitude'. When you add space, the terminal thinks that it is a different command.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w6ey46gf0yvg30s/Screenshot%20from%202016-10-12%2003%3A30%3A27.png?dl=0 okay so i did and it thankfully worked , still havent read all the man but i have a question other than it not working , where is or what is the aptitude , how can i recall it in terminal if im to ever close it etc

Comment: man is installed just like any other software. It is installed as a package. Whenever you have a problem use it like how I told you to. You can reuse it even after closing the terminal.

Comment: If my answer helped then please accept it by the clicking the green tick on the left.